# how to leave the name only numbers and underscores

Tags: python

I have many format name files
ep00_seq00_sh00
need to make them
00_00_00 in the blender so that they themselves are inserted into the field I need. I can get the file name. But how to cut it is a mystery

[image]

Comment: can you pls show us what format name files you mean and into what fields you want them insert in? maybe some screenshots?

Comment: took screenshots

Comment: Lol I think this is something I would do with a batch script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re
name = 'sds01_as02'
print(re.sub(r'[^0-9_]+','',name))
# outputs '01_02'
```